# AWS Cloudfront ignores Default Root Object - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I can't figure out why AWS cloudfront appears to ignore the default root object and instead gives Access Denied.

I have default root object set to `index.html` with no other characters.  This was set using cloud formation and I am confident the YAML there has absolutely nothing extra.

When I try to access http://example.com/foo/bar I get an access denied error from S3 such as:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>526EKP3GS3FTJXJ7</RequestId>
<HostId>eBXbDoh/ZhW1D66W9Xf8jKDEoCqEcBoCeEt01v7NO+gzrTv52GArRJh2wa/YZciwI6+NEG4T1yU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

But when I go to access http://example.com/foo/bar/index.html the page loads just fine.

Comment: Default object works only at root of the distribution. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html

Comment: @AnkushJain yeah I just found that. Not for the first time I find myself wondering "Why, AWS? Why!"

Comment: I already have a lambda on it, I'll follow this: https://medium.com/@chrispointon/default-files-in-s3-subdirectories-using-cloudfront-and-lambda-edge-941100a3c629

Comment: Oh, you are using Lambda@Edge, I wasn’t aware. That should work ideally, may be some misconfiguration is creating issue..

Comment: @PhilipCouling *"Why, AWS, why?"* Because it's the default **root** object.  If you want index documents, you can configure your bucket for web site hosting and set the index document name in the S3 website configuration, then connect to the bucket's web site endpoint from CloudFront using a custom origin (not an S3 origin) and set the origin protocol policy to HTTP.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That doesn't answer the question of "Why, AWS? Why!". I see the definition, that's not the problem. The question is more accurately "why implement a chocolate teapot or an inflatable dart board?"

Comment: @AnkushJain no the Lambda isn't there for redirections like this, it's an Oauth implementation. But sneaking in an index document path rewrite will cost like 4 lines of code in the existing lambda

Comment: @PhilipCouling the reason is that this feature, as its name suggests, was never intended to do what you are looking for.  An HTTP request for the root of the bucket produces a bucket listing, and you wouldn't want that to be accessible through CloudFront. This is an workaround for that. Returning index documents at arbitrary paths are not trivial to do correctly, because you first need to redirect the browser from `/foo/bar` to `/foo/bar/` which would subsequently be silently handled as `/foo/bar/index.html`. This requires a level of bucket introspection that CloudFront doesn't have access to.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no you don't need to forward /foo/bar to /foo/bar/ !! That's not true at all. this might be a common behaviour in some web servers but it's not typically relied on by URLs in HTML and it's not standardised. Indeed RFC1738 section 2.3 makes it clear that /foo/bar and /foo/bar/ are different URLS. The only thing you need to support index documents is serving the index document when the url ends /.  That's exactly how I've fixed this using a lambda.

Comment: @PhilipCouling S3 static websites also redirect to add the trailing slash when it's missing, and you can point CloudFront to a web site hosting endpoint, so I don't know what to tell you other than the fact that the default root object feature has an entirely different intended purpose that predates the availability of even the S3 static web site hosting feature.  Bonus trivia: for an S3 origin, the only way to get a 404 instead of a 403 returned from S3 for missing objects is to give CloudFront the `s3:ListBucket` permission, which is also what turns on the bucket listing at the root.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if such redirection really is required it would only take one hook in response to a 404 from the bucket. If /foo/bar is not found then head /foo/bar/index.html and if that is found replace 404 with 302. That's really not as complicated as you are making out and doesn't invent some new half baked concept that maps to nothing from other web servers or CDNs. You are trying to justify a feature invented but the need for it doesn't really stack up.